# Problem With texture or UV I'm not sure

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I'm a beginner and I have a problem with one of my models. I can't seem to add a texture to it. When I try to apply a texture, it applies only the general color of it. Every texture paint I do on it only applies in the "texture paint" tab but not in the shading one. My nodes seem to be connected correctly, I unwrapped my model so i can't seem to understand what's the problem.

I already tried different UV unwraps as well different textures and flipping the normals. I'm quite stuck here

Here are some screencaps

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

(update in the comments)

Comment: Have you tried using a *Texture Coordinate* node in your material?

Comment: Hi. Images should be added using the built-in uploader so the images appear in the post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. You can use the [edit] link under your post to change this.

Comment: it looks like it has a texture... maybe share your file (make sure you've packed the image): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: So i used a texture coordinate node but it seems alsmost impossible to set up. My file doesn't have a texture i wanna use yet, i've been using placeholders and test textures to try and make the model match my futur texture painting but i can't seem to make it work. I'm gonna link my file to see if you people can help me understand what is wrong with my mesh, why it need the texture coordinate node to show up and why it seems impossible to setup the coordinates for a texture to be used. How do I make it look like the shading tab ? 

https://imgur.com/a/XwizC29

Comment: The screen caps are small and uneasy to read. Could you upload the blend file (with textures packed in it), as proposed by @moonboots above?

Comment: Yes, sorry my upload was taking long, as i said, any texture will do, i'm just trying to be able to paint on a plank one and have it reflected onto my shading, so i havent packed anything it's just my blend file. It's now in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two UV Maps here, just change the one used for rendering:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the solutions